# Is there a way to analytically compute the recurrence time of a finite Markov process?

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains

Let $X_t$ be an ergodic (time-homogeneous) Markov process (in discrete or continuous time) on a finite state space $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Let $T(X_0)$ be the stopping time given by the infimum of times such that $X$ has covered the space (i.e., for all $j$ with $1 \le j \le n$ there exists some $t_j \le T(X_0)$ s.t. $X_{t_j} = j$) and $X_{T(X_0)} = X_0$. Clearly $T(X_0)$ dominates the cover time of $X$. I would expect it to be dominated in turn by the sum of the cover time and the expected [hitting time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitting_time) of $X_0$ starting from a state chosen w/r/t the invariant distribution $p$.

Define the *recurrence time* as $\sum_{X_0} p(X_0) \cdot \mathbb{E}_{X_0} T(X_0)$, where again the first term is the invariant distribution of $X$.

Now it has been quite a while (early 2000s) since I looked at cover and hitting times, but I recall that while the [fundamental matrix](http://books.google.com/books?id=KF0LgxRCgQsC&pg=PA226) (in discrete time) or the ["deviation matrix"](http://doc.utwente.nl/62339/) (in continuous time) give lots of information about hitting times, computing the cover time is hard. I am aware of the [Matthews bound](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.PR/0005121), but I do not know of a simpler way to compute the cover time than by simulating the chain. In particular, I don't know of an analytical approach to this quantity.

I am in the same situation w/r/t the recurrence time, and it is this quantity that interests me much more than the cover time *per se*. But both are of some interest/utility to me.

So my questions are:

> 1. Has the recurrence time (or a similar quantity besides the cover time or first return time) been treated anywhere?
> 2. Are there known analytical results on computing or at least (besides the Matthews
>      bound) bounding cover times or
>      recurrence times?

Comment: The coupon-collecting approach is exponential. Does that count as analytic?

Comment: Can you provide a reference?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0609

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a response to a comment.

The [coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) is elementary. I don't have a particular scholarly reference in mind, but rather the technique of the proofs. There are a few proofs of the $n H_n$ expected time to collect all coupons. One possibility is that you can compute the expected time to collect the $k$th new coupon, 
$n/(n-k+1)$. That uses a lot of symmetry you don't have for a general Markov process. Here, you have transition probabilities and times on (current location, subset visited so far).

Analogous to what I did [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13171/how-many-trial-picks-expectedly-sufficient-to-cover-a-sample-space/13217#13217), you can use inclusion-exclusion. The expected time to cover everything (with discrete time) is the sum of the probability that you haven't covered everything by time $t-1$, which you can express as

$$\sum_t \sum_{S\subset V} -1^{|S|+1}Prob(\{X_i\}_{i\lt t}\cap S = \emptyset) $$

where $V$ = $\{1,...,n\}$. You can switch the order of summation to get about $2^n$ analytically solvable problems about avoiding particular subsets.

$$\sum_{S\subset V} -1^{|S|+1} A(S)$$

where $A(S)$ = expected time before you first enter $S$.

The same holds for continuous time.

Comment: Those sums should be over the nonempty subsets. 

Comment: Douglas, thanks. Do you know of a reference that deals with this approach for generic finite ergodic Markov processes?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. The method of estimating the time to visit the kth new vertex of a graph is present in "Short Random Walks On Graphs" by Greg Barnes and Uriel Feige.

Answer (score 1):

http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4371 might be useful.

A note regarding your remark:
"Clearly T(X0) dominates the cover time of X. I would expect it to be dominated in turn by the sum of the cover time and the expected hitting time of X0 starting from a state chosen w/r/t the invariant distribution p."

This is false (unless I'm misreading it). If you start from 0 on the discrete interval {0,1,..,n}, then after covering you have to return to 0 from n, which takes longer than returning to 0 from a uniformly random point.

Comment: Thanks; I caught this myself, see comments to my question.

Comment: Also I had in mind a cover time of the form used in this paper, otherwise you're quite correct.