# Rationality of the sum of the reciprocals of the values of a polynomial function at the positive integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $f$ be a polynomial function of degree at least $2$ with integer coefficients,
and assume that $f(n)$ is nonzero for any positive integer $n$.

**Question:** Is it algorithmically decidable whether
$$
  S(f) \ := \ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{f(n)}
$$
is rational or not? -- Which are the known necessary or sufficient criteria
for the rationality or the irrationality of the value of this expression?

*Examples:* $S(n^2) = \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $S(n^3) = \zeta(3)$
are irrational, while $S(n^2+n) = 1$ is rational.

Comment: Isn't it already open for arbitrary $n^{2k+1}$?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there is any such.

Comment: @SashaP: As far as I know, yes. -- But still it is conceivable that someone knows how to prove algorithmic undecidability, or can give criteria which apply to classes of polynomials which do *not* include $n^{2k+1}$.

Comment: Asking about algorithmic decidability is probably the wrong question. It could be that $S(f)$ is irrational except in certain cases where rationality is obvious. Then it would be decidable, but we wouldn't be able to *prove* that it is decidable. I think you're really just interested in which cases the irrationality is *known*.

Comment: @TimothyChow: This is quite possible. Do you know of any heuristics which suggest that $S(f)$ is irrational except in cases where it is obviously rational (I mean one which is better than "the rationals are countable, but the irrationals are not, so assuming some 'well-behaved' kind of random distribution, almost all $S(f)$ should be irrational")?

Answer (score 1):

A perhaps not so interesting class of examples where the sums in question are known to be either transcendental or explicitly computable algebraics is referenced here:

https://mathoverflow.net/a/33586

Perhaps that can direct you to more papers on the subject.

Edit: I should perhaps also mention that there are lattice based algorithms that can reconstruct minimal polynomials of algebraics with a good enough approximations. Thus, given that the degree and logarithmic height of these values are bounded by computable constants, you may take a large partial sum, use said lattice techniques, and if you don't get a match conclude that it is in fact a transcendental.

Comment: Thanks for a start! -- Though I don't see that the criterion in the post you refer to would decide any nontrivial case ... .

Comment: In the last paragraph: why are "the degree and logarithmic height of these values bounded by computable constants"?

Answer (score 1):

If $f(n)$ has only simple rational zeros, the paper [Transcendental infinite sums](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S001935770180001X/pdf?md5=6316fb0bdf69d129871b5882c28b6c5f&pid=1-s2.0-S001935770180001X-main.pdf)
is related.

p.3:

**Corollary 2.1**. Let $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ be
periodic $\mod q$. Let $Q(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ have simple rational zeros.
If

$$ S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{Q(n)}$$

converges, then $S$ equals a computable algebraic number or
$ S \not \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. In the later case we have ...

Comment: What do we have in the later case?

Comment: They give bounds for the latter case, check the public paper.